# Time not working as expected using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working on a web application where i want to find the local time for different time zones. I am using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in order to accomplish this task. The problem is that returning time does not work as expected. For example:

```
moment().tz("Europe/London")._d;
```

will return **Thu Aug 15 2013 01:22:23 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)** but at the same time local hour at London is **Thu Aug 14 2013 22:22:23** so there is a 3 hour difference. Can anyone explain why this is happening and suggest a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Is timezone setup correctly in operating system?

Comment: @zerkms Currently on my computer i am on the time zone Europe/Athens but i want to find the local time on a different time zone than my computer. So my operating system time does not matter i suppose. But yes it is correct.

Comment: @Juhana Yes i have constructed the Europe/London time zone.

Comment: @Giorgos Manoltzas: my question was about if the timezone is correct. It is indeed doesn't matter what it is, but it should be correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `._d` property.  The underscore is there to indicate that it's internal.  (Since that is a `Date`, it will always show as if it were in the local time zone, because that's how JavaScript works.)

Instead use one of the output methods, such as `.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time= moment.tz(value).format('LTS'),
var date= moment.tz(value).format('LL'),
var abbr= moment.tz.zone(value).abbr(moment.utc().valueOf()), //PST,IST
var name= moment.tz.zone(value).name); //Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: *Can anyone explain why this is happening and suggest a solution?* -- This may be a solution, but it helps the original questioner as well as future visitors if you add an explanation of what happened and why this might be a solution.