# Moment.js - how do I get the current NYC time using moment-timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I know that I can do `moment()` to get the current time, but I want to specify the timezone to be 'America/New_York' and have the time correctly reflect that timezone.  How can I do this?

If I do:

```
moment().tz('America/New_York');
```

then it returns a time that is 5 hours behind the current time in New York.  Apparently it picks up the current time that my computer reports, assumes this time is UTC even though it is not, then adjusts this time by the timezone offset -- this results in the incorrect time for the given timezone.

Comment: I used this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/88/) to check the accuracy of moment-timezones against timeandddate.com... Seems to be off by 2 minutes but not 5 hours. Also, you can adjust the offset with `zone.offset`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time not working as expected using moment.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242612/time-not-working-as-expected-using-moment-js)

Comment: You are looking a the `_d` property of the moment object.  Don't do that  (see the dup post I linked).  Also, you have a typo - "America", not "American".